# Trying to bypass Cloudflare security to login on upwork to scrape

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to log in on `Upwork` with my crawler to solve a tech challenge, this is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cloudscraper

url = "https://www.upwork.com/ab/account-security/login"
username = ******************
password = ******************
secret = ******************
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

def main():
    response = scraper.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    # login_field = soup.find('input', {'name': 'login[username]'})
    # login_field['value'] = username

    # login_button = soup.find('button', {'id': 'login_password_continue'})

    form_data = {}
    form_data['username'] = username
    form_data['password'] = password

    # I have tried ['login[username]'] and ['login[password]'] as well


    response = scraper.post(url, data=form_data)
```

I do receive a 200 status code, but I keep getting bouncing back to the login webpage due to some `Cloudfare` security measures, any solution for this? or should I try to go with `Selenium`?

Comment: What kind of IP do you have? Residential, datacenter, mobile?

Comment: It's a simple residential environment

Comment: Nice project `cloudscraper`. They say: Due to Cloudflare continually changing and hardening their protection page, cloudscraper requires a JavaScript Engine/interpreter to solve Javascript challenges. This allows the script to easily impersonate a regular web browser without explicitly deobfuscating and parsing Cloudflare's Javascript. Do you deal with **JS** somewhere?

Comment: Moreover, Upwork have an API. I requested my access 1 month before, they said the process takes 1-2 weeks, but still no access. That sucks!

Comment: I'm not explicitly dealing with JS anywhere on my code

Comment: Yeah, looks like Selenium would be far easier

Comment: Yes, selenium would be better, but if the webpage already is showing Cloudflare, you should use Undetected Chromedriver, i been using it in a few projects and it works just fine. pip install undetected-chromedriver